# How to open app using the URL android

Tags: html

I am trying to open application on android phone via Browser, Is their anyway to open any application using the ** URL ** in an andoid phone via Chrome, by using HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of these URLs is pretty simple and an example of a real URL that you can use is:

```
intent://#Intent;action=android.in
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the format provided by the app vendor. for example `whatsapp://` should be used to open whatsapp and `magnet:?` to open torrent app. Likewise you have to use in links